# system.data.Entity is giving error?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4.1

I am trying to add this system.data.Entity namespace in my project and it si not recognizing it. I searched for it on MSDN and it asked me to download EntityFramework 4.1, whcih I did and it is still not recognized.

I am not sure why?

Comment: Please post some actual code - and have you added a reference to the appropriate assembly?

Comment: How to post code here? I tried but it all came out ugly..... is ther eany code tag here?

Comment: In addition to `System.Data.Entity` you must add `EntityFramework.dll` to your references. That's the assembly you downloaded with EF 4.1 and it contains the DbContext specific stuff.

Comment: THAT was the answer I need EntityFramework.dll. Thank you so much.

Comment: Consider using NuGet for stuff like this in the future, it will add the assemblies that you need automatically

Answer (score 0):

In your web.config, add this line:

```
<add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
```

Comment: Actually ti works after adding System.Entity from the reference I also added your Assembly code in my Web.Config but now I am trying System.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions and that is not being recognized. I am nto sure why?